# sed: -i may not be used with stdin #Error

Tags: bash, sed

I'm getting an error with the following

`find . -name "*" -type f | xargs grep -l "xyz" | sed -i '' 's/'${line}'/'${rep}'/g'`

`sed: -i may not be used with stdin`

what's gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asuming that you're trying to sed something only in the files that contain xyz, you will have to xargs again

```
find . -name "*" -type f | xargs grep -l "xyz" |xargs  sed -i "s/'${line}'/'${rep}'/g"
```

Answer (score 1):

`-i` is for inline file editing and you are just piping find command's output to `sed` in stdin hence that error shows up.

Try this `find command` instead:

```
find . -name "*" -type f -exec sed -i '' "s/${line}/${rep}/g" '{}' \;
```

PS: `-name "*"` can also be skipped here.

Answer (score 1):

When we are using the find command we can't connect the output with the pipe( | ). So you can use the -exec with find command to execute more commands.